# Python: Refactor code to remove global variable

Tags: python, refactoring, global-variables

I am currently using a global variable in my code called `correct`. Considering globals are frowned upon, is there a better way to set up my code to "protect" the global variable?

```
from random import randint
from random import choice

lower  = int(raw_input("Enter a lower integer constraint: "))
higher = int(raw_input("Enter a higher integer constraint: "))

correct = 0


def gen_randoms(lower, higher):
    integers = list()
    for x in xrange(4):
        rand_int = randint(lower, higher)
        integers.append(rand_int)
    return integers


def gen_equation(integers):
    nums = map(str, integers)
    operators = ['*', '+', '-']
    equation = 'num op num op num op num'
    while 'op' in equation:
        equation = equation.replace('op', choice(operators), 1)
    while 'num' in equation:
        equation = equation.replace('num', choice(nums), 1)
    print equation
    return equation


def evaluate(equation):
    answer = eval(equation)
    print answer
    return answer


def compare_answers(gen_answer, game):
    global correct
    user_answer = int(raw_input("What is the answer? "))
    if user_answer == gen_answer:
        correct += 1
        print 'Correct!'
        print 'Current streak: %s' % str(correct)
        game()
    else:
        print 'Incorrect!'
        correct = 0
        game()


def game():
    nums = gen_randoms(lower, higher)
    this_equation = gen_equation(nums)
    gen_answer = evaluate(this_equation)
    compare_answers(gen_answer, game)


game()
```

Comment: Have it be an input and return from compare_answers() ?

Comment: The simplest way is to inline `compare_answers()` into `game()`, and move the variable `correct` into `game()` as well.

Comment: Also, the fact that you're using tail recursion in `game()` and `compare_answers()` means you'll run out of stack space eventually.

Comment: @NayukiMinase Thanks, can you explain what you mean by "inlining"?

Comment: Another way to eliminate the global variable is to create a `Game` class with an instance variable called `correct`. This would serve to limit the scope of `correct`.

Comment: You have three global variables there, by the way, solely taking care of `correct` will leave you more work to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably do it something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""Equation solving game."""

from random import randint
from random import choice


def gen_randoms(lower, higher):

    """Generates four random numbers between provided bounds."""

    integers = [randint(lower, higher) for x in range(4)]
    return integers


def gen_equation(integers):

    """Generates a random equation from four provided integers."""

    nums = [str(i) for i in integers]
    operators = ['*', '+', '-']
    equation = 'num op num op num op num'
    while 'op' in equation:
        equation = equation.replace('op', choice(operators), 1)
    while 'num' in equation:
        equation = equation.replace('num', choice(nums), 1)
    return equation


def evaluate(equation):

    """Evaluates an equation."""

    return eval(equation)


def main():

    """Main game function."""

    lower = int(raw_input("Enter a lower integer constraint: "))
    higher = int(raw_input("Enter a higher integer constraint: "))
    nums = gen_randoms(lower, higher)
    streak = 0

    while True:
        this_equation = gen_equation(nums)
        print this_equation

        user_answer = raw_input("What is the answer? ('Q' to quit) ")

        if user_answer.lower()[0] == 'q':
            break

        gen_answer = evaluate(this_equation)
        print 'The answer was: %d' % gen_answer

        if gen_answer == int(user_answer):
            streak += 1
            print 'Correct!'
            print 'Current streak: %d' % streak
        else:
            streak = 0
            print 'Incorrect!'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

A few comments:

- Each function should generally only do one thing, so if a function evaluates an equation, it's usually better to not have it print the equation, too.
- Figuring out where the variables ought to go becomes a lot easier when you do this, since you don't need to pass them around so much as you have to when each function does several different things.
- The main game logic here is sufficiently straightforward that you don't really need to break it out of your main `game()` function (or `main()` function, in my example) so much, it doesn't overcomplicate things to leave it in there. If you wanted to do some more error checking (e.g. seeing if the user entered an invalid number, and you want to go back and ask for more input if so) then you might want to break it out some more.

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
def game(correct=0):    
    nums = gen_randoms(lower, higher)  
    this_equation = gen_equation(nums)  
    gen_answer = evaluate(this_equation)  
    correct = compare_answers(gen_answer, game, correct)  
    game(correct)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
def game():
    correct = 0
    while True:
        nums = gen_randoms(lower, higher)
        this_equation = gen_equation(nums)
        gen_answer = evaluate(this_equation)
        user_answer = int(raw_input("What is the answer? "))
        if user_answer == gen_answer:
            correct += 1
            print 'Correct!'
            print 'Current streak: %s' % str(correct)
        else:
            print 'Incorrect!'
            correct = 0
```

Then delete these pieces of old code: `game()`, `compare_answers()`, and the global variable `correct`.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove the `global correct` from `compare_answers`
2. set `game` to take in a keyword argument `correct` with default value `0`. `def game(correct =0)`
3. set `compare_answers` to take a third argument `correct`
4. when calling `game` from `compare_answers` pass in `correct`

**i.e.:**

```
def compare_answers(gen_answer, game, correct):
    user_answer = int(raw_input("What is the answer? "))
    if user_answer == gen_answer:
        correct += 1
        print 'Correct!'
        print 'Current streak: %s' % str(correct)
        game(correct)
    else:
        print 'Incorrect!'
        correct = 0
        game(correct)


def game(correct = 0):
    nums = gen_randoms(lower, higher)
    this_equation = gen_equation(nums)
    gen_answer = evaluate(this_equation)
    compare_answers(gen_answer, game, correct)


game()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking @JoelCornett's suggestion and creating a class:

```
from random import randint
from random import choice

class Math_Problem_Generator(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.lower = int(raw_input("Enter a lower integer constraint: "))
        self.higher = int(raw_input("Enter a higher integer constraint: "))
        self.correct = 0
        self.game(self.correct)


    def gen_randoms(self, lower, higher):
        integers = list()
        for x in xrange(4):
            rand_int = randint(lower, higher)
            integers.append(rand_int)
        return integers


    def gen_equation(self, integers):
        nums = map(str, integers)
        operators = ['*', '+', '-']
        equation = 'num op num op num op num'
        while 'op' in equation:
            equation = equation.replace('op', choice(operators), 1)
        while 'num' in equation:
            equation = equation.replace('num', choice(nums), 1)
        print equation
        return equation


    def evaluate(self, equation):
        answer = eval(equation)
        print answer
        return answer


    def compare_answers(self, gen_answer):
        user_answer = int(raw_input("What is the answer? "))
        if user_answer == gen_answer:
            self.correct += 1
            print 'Correct!'
            print 'Current streak: %s' % str(self.correct)
            self.game(self.correct)
        else:
            print 'Incorrect!'
            self.correct = 0
            self.game(self.correct)


    def game(self, correct):
        nums = self.gen_randoms(self.lower, self.higher)
        this_equation = self.gen_equation(nums)
        gen_answer = self.evaluate(this_equation)
        self.compare_answers(gen_answer)
        self.game()


Math_Problem_Generator()
```

Comment: FYI, while this works, it's not really good OOP, and it's still just a procedural program lightly wrapped in OOP syntax. For instance, three of your five methods (excluding `__init__()`) don't access any instance data or call any instance methods, which suggests pretty strongly they don't belong in the class. It removes the global variables issue, but ends up substituting one bad practice for another.

Comment: Isn't it also a bad practice to have the package's `__init__()` call `self.game()`? You should separate `game()` or `run()` out from `__init()__` . You can always still declare and run it (anonymously) as a one-liner with `Math_Problem_Generator().run()`

Answer (score 0):

Collect your results in the caller, and then print the count. This version gets rid of your other globals, `lower` and `higher`.

```
def compare_answers(gen_answer):
    user_answer = int(raw_input("What is the answer? "))
    return user_anser == gen_answer

def game():

    correct = 0
    play_again = 'Y'

    while play_again.lower() == 'y':
        lower  = int(raw_input("Enter a lower integer constraint: "))
        higher = int(raw_input("Enter a higher integer constraint: "))
        nums = gen_randoms(lower, higher)
        this_equation = gen_equation(nums)
        gen_answer = evaluate(this_equation)
        if compare_answers(gen_answer):
           correct += 1
           print('You were right! Your winning streak is {0}'.format(correct))
        else:
           print('Sorry, your answer was wrong. :(')
           correct = 0

        play_again = raw_input('Would you like to play again? (Y/N): ')
```